# Export to word document Nested tables using DocX library in c#, can't open document

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, docx, novacode-docx

I have created word document (.doc and .docx) using DocX library in .net c#. I have used nested tables in this word document. Now the problem is that, whenever I try to open this generated document, it gives warning message like this :
"We are sorry. We can;t open  because we found a problem with its contents."

Getting this message if I click on Details button. : 
"Ambiguous cell mapping encountered. Possible missing paragraph element.

elements are required before every ".

If I do not use nested table and use single table then its working fine and not giving any warning message while opening that word document.

So, can anyone help me here to how avoid such warning problems if I have nested tables in generating word document using DocX library in .Net C#. ?

Thanks in advance.

Herin.